# How ro retrive SQLite data from Icloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, icloud

I am saving my app's data which is present in SQLite in Icloud in ".csv" file format.Its working properly and its getting saved in perfect manner.My requirement was extended i.e., how to get data from Icloud and also how to restore in my app's database.

I googled it and found few samples and also tutorials but I did'nt get proper solution.If any body has done this please guide me.

Comment: Rollback on useless minor edit. Please don't use code formatting for things that aren't code.

Comment: Then what's your suggestion? @Lundin

Comment: Sorrry, my comment had nothing to do with the contents of your question, I'm merely doing edit reviews and stopped some user who tried to clutter down your question by changing the formatting in strange ways.

Comment: How are you getting the file into iCloud? There are multiple APIs, and all provide for both upload and download. You almost certainly want to keep using the same API, but you didn't say which one that is.